# Remove new line character from csv file, matching certain criteria

Tags: csv, character, line

**ï..Date.Installed    OrganizationID  Organization.Name   SiteCurrentlyAuthorizedForLEM**
22-Dec-08   187 St. Alexius Medical Center  TRUE
5 is 81 and above
4 is 80 to 80
3 is 75 to 79
2 is 60 to 74
1 is 59 and below   H   81  80
22-Dec-08   187 St. Alexius Medical Center  TRUE
5 is 2.55 and above
4 is 2.3 to 2.54
3 is 2 to 2.29
2 is 1.8 to 1.99
1 is 1.79 and below H   2.55    2.3
22-Dec-08   187 St. Alexius Medical Center  TRUE
5 is 100 and above
4 is 99 to 99
3 is 98 to 98
2 is 97 to 97
1 is 96 and below   H   100 99

I have the following csv file. The problem is line wrapping. The header line is fine and so is the second line (starts with 22-Dec-08). The third line should also start with 22-Dec-08 and so on. How Can I get rid of the new line characters from the lines in between( 5 is 81 ....), so each new row starts with the Date?

**ï..Date.Installed OrganizationID Organization.Name          SiteCurrentlyAuthorizedForLEM..**
22-Dec-08      187           St. Alexius Medical Center TRUE....
22-Dec-08      187           St. Alexius Medical Center TRUE....

Answer (score 0):

How are you writing to CSV file? Write the below function in a loop and this will add text in one line.

```
    string delimiter = ",";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)  
       sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[index]));  

    File.AppendAllText(filePath,sb.ToString());
```